# ¿Cuál es el tipo de dato para la hora en grails?

Tags: grails, gorm

Tengo un atributo el cual es para  la hora, lo intenté usando **Time** y **Hour** pero no funciona.

```
class Actividad {
...
Time hora_limite
..
}

class Actividad {
...
Time hora_limite
..
}
```

Otengo el siguiente error al compilar:

```
unable to resolve class Time
```

Comment: lo resolviste? tengo el mismo problema

Comment: No como yo quisiera, lo que hice fue usar Date para la fecha, ya que Date también incluye la hora.